# Why does mypy complain about Any as return annotation and how should I annotate a return value that can be anything?

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have a class that is essentially a wrapper around a dictionary:

```
class Wrapper(dict):

    ...

    def __getitem__(self, item: Hashable) -> Any:
        return self.wrapped[item]
```

When checking the annotations with `mypy`, it yields an `Explicit "Any" is not allowed` when checking this code. My guess is that this stems from the concept that `Any` is the ancestor and successor of all other types. How should I annotate such function where I want to allow anything to be returned?

Comment: I would guess that they want you to just remove the annotation, but I'm still surprised that an explicit `Any` would be actually forbidden.

Comment: Also, you appear to be making the common mistake of inheriting from `dict` *and* having another dict as an instance variable. Don't do that; pick one or the other, or you'll end up wasting space and having very confusing bugs where data ends up in one dict when you were expecting it to land in the other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens when the `disallow_any_explicit` is set to `True` for that module in the configuration file. Just remove that option for the default `False`.

Comment: This removes the error, but doesn't fix the problem. I posted [my own answer](/a/71228606/4518341) with what I believe is the actual solution.

Comment: On reviewing this again, I think I was wrong, though I'm still shaky on type theory. I think what you should actually do is have the return annotation of `__getitem__` agree with the values of `self.wrapped`, like in [Azat's answer](/a/51475351/4518341).

Answer (score 2):

We need to tell `mypy` that types of `self.wrapped` container are related to the ones of `Wrapper` methods, we can do that using [`typing.TypeVar` instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) for keys and values in our case.

So we can end up with something like

```py
from collections import abc
from typing import (Dict,
                    Iterator,
                    TypeVar)


class Wrapper(abc.MutableMapping):
    KeyType = TypeVar('KeyType')
    ValueType = TypeVar('ValueType')

    def __init__(self, wrapped: Dict[KeyType, ValueType]) -> None:
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __delitem__(self, key: KeyType) -> None:
        del self.wrapped[key]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.wrapped)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[KeyType]:
        return iter(self.wrapped)

    def __setitem__(self, key: KeyType, value: ValueType) -> None:
        self.wrapped[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key: KeyType) -> ValueType:
        return self.wrapped[key]
```

## Test

Running `mypy` with `--disallow-any-explicit` flag causes no errors/warnings.

## Note about inheritance/composition

If one really needs a custom mapping I'll recommend to not mix inheritance from `dict` with using `self.wrapped` `dict`-field as it can cause a lot of pain in the future (we should re-define all of its methods or sometimes you will be using `self.wrapped` and sometimes not).

We can simply use `MutableMapping` ABC from [`collections.abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) and define basic methods (like `__getitem__`), the rest (`keys()`, `values`, `items()` are defined already).

Answer (score 0):

You have provided insufficient information in the question to recreate this error but if your sole question is:

> How should I annotate such function where I want to allow anything to be returned?

The simple answer is **don't annotate it at all**. It will by default act as `Any`.

Comment: Is this really the answer? I tried it but now I'm getting *"Function is missing a type annotation for one or more arguments [no-untyped-def]"*. Are those two configuration options mutually exclusive, or is there something I'm missing? I tried annotating with `object` and it seems to work.